# React Router Set Up in VS Code

Tags: reactjs, npm, react-router

I am learning React Js and the IDE I am using is VS Code. I am not able to install the react router dom using the command `npm install react-router dom`. Whenever I type `npm install react-router-dom` I get the message. react-router is not getting installed.

```
Windows PowerShell Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.
up to date, audited 1407 packages in 4s
169 packages are looking for funding
run `npm fund for details
8 moderate severity vulnerabilities
To address all issues (including breaking changes), run:
npm audit fix --force
Run `npm audit for details.
```

Comment: please share the error details. The system is already giving a suggestion to address the problem. npm  audit fix --force
give a try in vscode terminal also.

Comment: Are you sure it's not installed? You don't mention any errors. Run `npm list react-router-dom` and verify what is installed in your project directory.

Comment: Its just a warning, the package is installed anyway and you can use react router

Comment: I tried npm audit fix --force.. but it doesn't work instead it shows the same message again.. The router dom also ins't installed as I cross-checked it in the file directory twice...

Comment: What does "cross-checked it in the file directory twice" mean? Did you run `npm list react-router-dom`, from the project directory, to log what is installed?

Answer (score 1):

Try `npm install react-router-dom`

Comment: How is this an answer when it's literally the command OP said they used?

Comment: @DrewReese its not, he has a typo.

Comment: I see. It may be a typo. If so, that's a reason to VTC.

Comment: Thank you for all your answers but I later tried and saw that the react router had already been installed...it's now working...thanks

Answer (score 0):

I tried npm audit fix --force.. but it doesn't work instead it shows the same message again..

10 high severity vulnerabilities

To address all issues (including breaking changes), run:
npm audit fix --force

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Type `npm i react-router-dom` in your terminal and click enter. It will work.